# What makes a quest fall under "Miscellaneous"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Right now, I've got 23 "Miscellaneous" and only 16 "regular" quests.  Sometimes, a Miscellaneous quest is just as complex and trying (if not more so) as some regular quests, and occasionally I believe one of the former will lead or turn into one of the latter.

The delineation between the two categories seems rather arbitrary to me so far.  Is there some common criteria that separates them from each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Miscellaneous quests usually encompass every quest *except* for those that are part of the main quest line, faction quest lines, cities and settlements, or ones that involve the Divines, Daedric, and Forsworn.

Miscellaneous quests can include bounty, dungeon, Thane quests, crafting tutorials, or random/open world interactions.

Many of these quests can be obtained from any innkeeper, others by rumors, conversations, and letters/couriers.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the _Dark Brotherhood_ line, or _Companions_ etc etc as part of the main questline. Is just that miscellaneous quests are usually supposed to be simpler and shorter.